# kendo angular UI wizard

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using kendo angular 2 and need to implement wizard(multiple pages) form style.

As part of requirment I need to do validations in each page before moving to next page. I see **scrollview** component but it seems it does not have much control over doing validations .

please suggest me what is the possible solution for this.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is [feature request](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-feedback/suggestions/33906667-stepper-component) for stepper component.

I had approximately same problem and I solved it by creating custom stepper component. I get inspiration in [source code](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib/stepper) of [Angular material stepper component](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview).

Because there are to many files I prepare quick [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yusos5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Component is incomplete, but it is a start.